# Error while electron js / builder on an existing react js based project

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have full functioning  project running React js with Rails as backend

Planning to build desktop apps using electron.js

its running perfectly on dev

```
PORT=3001 concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3001 && electron .\
```

when i run yarn run electron-builder -m i got below error

```
 • electron-builder  version=22.10.5 os=20.3.0
  • loaded configuration  file=package.json ("build" field)
  • loaded parent configuration  preset=react-cra
  • Specified application directory equals to project dir — superfluous or wrong configuration  appDirectory=.
  • description is missed in the package.json  appPackageFile=/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/package.json
  • writing effective config  file=out/builder-effective-config.yaml
  • rebuilding native dependencies  dependencies=canvas@2.7.0, fsevents@1.2.13, node-sass@4.14.1 platform=darwin arch=x64
  • rebuilding native dependency  name=canvas version=2.7.0
  • rebuilding native dependency  name=fsevents version=1.2.13
  • rebuilding native dependency  name=node-sass version=4.14.1
  • packaging       platform=darwin arch=x64 electron=11.4.2 appOutDir=out/mac
  • Unpacking electron zip  zipPath=undefined
  ⨯ editions-autoloader-none-broadened: Unable to determine a suitable edition, even after broadening.  stackTrace=
Error: editions-autoloader-none-broadened: Unable to determine a suitable edition, even after broadening.
at new Errlop (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/errlop/edition-es5/index.js:61:18)
at Object.errtion (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/util.js:23:14)
at determineEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:317:21)
at solicitEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:350:16)
at Object.requirePackage (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:364:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/istextorbinary/index.cjs:4:38)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/app-builder-lib/electron-osx-sign/util.js:135:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
↳ Error: editions-autoloader-none-suitable: Unable to determine a suitable edition, as none were suitable.
at new Errlop (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/errlop/edition-es5/index.js:61:18)
at Object.errtion (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/util.js:23:14)
at determineEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:327:19)
at determineEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:312:12)
at solicitEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:350:16)
at Object.requirePackage (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:364:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/istextorbinary/index.cjs:4:38)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/app-builder-lib/electron-osx-sign/util.js:135:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
↳ Error: editions-autoloader-edition-incompatible: editions-autoloader-edition-incompatible: The edition [TypeScript source code made to be compatible with Deno] is not compatible with this environment.
at new Errlop (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/errlop/edition-es5/index.js:61:18)
at Object.errtion (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/util.js:23:14)
at determineEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:301:25)
at determineEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:312:12)
at solicitEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:350:16)
at Object.requirePackage (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:364:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/istextorbinary/index.cjs:4:38)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/app-builder-lib/electron-osx-sign/util.js:135:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
↳ Error: editions-autoloader-edition-incompatible: editions-autoloader-edition-incompatible: The edition [TypeScript compiled against ES2019 for Node.js 12 || 14 || 15 with Import for modules] is not compatible with this environment.
at new Errlop (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/errlop/edition-es5/index.js:61:18)
at Object.errtion (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/util.js:23:14)
at determineEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:301:25)
at determineEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:312:12)
at solicitEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:350:16)
at Object.requirePackage (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:364:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/istextorbinary/index.cjs:4:38)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/app-builder-lib/electron-osx-sign/util.js:135:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
↳ Error: editions-autoloader-edition-incompatible: editions-autoloader-edition-incompatible: The edition [TypeScript compiled against ES2019 for Node.js 10 || 12 || 14 || 15 with Require for modules] is not compatible with this environment.
at new Errlop (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/errlop/edition-es5/index.js:61:18)
at Object.errtion (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/util.js:23:14)
at determineEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:301:25)
at determineEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:312:12)
at solicitEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:350:16)
at Object.requirePackage (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:364:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/istextorbinary/index.cjs:4:38)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/app-builder-lib/electron-osx-sign/util.js:135:22)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)


at determineEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:312:12)
at solicitEdition (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:350:16)
at Object.requirePackage (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/editions/edition-es5/index.js:364:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/istextorbinary/index.cjs:4:38)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1118:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:982:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:875:14)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1022:19)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/app-builder-lib/electron-osx-sign/util.js:135:22)
```

i"m using OSX - Big Sur

Node - v13.14.0
Yarn - 1.22.10
and xcode 12.4

I thought this issue is just on osx. i got some other issue on windows build   `yarn run electron-builder -m`

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:697:50: note: 'remove_cv' declared here
    template <class _Tp> struct _LIBCPP_TEMPLATE_VIS remove_cv
                                                     ^
    1 error generated.
    make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
    gyp ERR! build error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
    gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
    gyp ERR! command "/Users/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/bin/node" "/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/node-sass/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
    gyp ERR! cwd /Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/node-sass
    gyp ERR! node -v v13.14.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    Build failed with error code: 1
    error Command failed with exit code 1.
    
                    command=/Users/admin/.nvm/versions/node/v13.14.0/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/yarn/bin/yarn.js run install
                    workingDir=/Users/admin/Dev/project/frontend/node_modules/node-sass
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: add full error code

Comment: @sharunkk i've added

Comment: @AnishMenon perhaps this will help? https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/5668

Answer (score 0):

Delete node_modules and run `npm i` again. After that should work.

To delete node_modules in command line use: `rm -R node_modules -f`.

It worked for me, building without errors after that.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem! It's a problem version NodeJS, I was using v16.16.0 and I done downgrade for v16.15.O.
Follow the steps after downgrade node:

- Delete Node Modules
- Delete Package-lock.json
- NPN Install

Now it's works and building.